# Dropdownmenu Tabkey pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to construct a simple dropdownmenu ([jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Elenktik/eagtg0y5/)) which should be accessible with the tab-key even if javascript is disabled.

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #08C;
}
ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul#nav > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```
<ul id='nav'>
  <li><a href='#'>Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to iterate through the entries with the tab-key with pure CSS?

I would like to iterate through the links as follows:

Menu 1 -> Eintrag 1 -> Eintrag 2 -> Menu 2 -> Eintrag 1 -> Eintrag 2 -> Eintrag 3 -> Eintrag 4

With the CSS code

```
a:focus + ul{
   display: block;
 }
```

I can tab on **Menu 1** and then *Eintrag 1* and *Eintrag 2* are visible. Pressing tab again focuses *Eintrag 1* and then the ul is again not visible (because it gets display: none), so I cannot access *Eintrag 2*. Is there a simple CSS solution how to tab through all entries?

Answer (score 1):

Considering I understood your requirement correctly, here is my answer:

Tabs works like Radio buttons in some way. You can select only one at an instance. Why don't you associate every tab to a radio button and check for the current tab according to the selected radio button.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

#nav > li{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav label, #nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

li{  
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #08C;
}

ul ul{
  display:none;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul#nav input.tabset{
width:0px;
  height:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

ul#nav input.tabset:checked ~ ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id='nav'>
  <li><input class="tabset" id="menu1" name="tabset1" type="radio" /><label for="menu1" href='#'>Menu 1</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input class="tabset" id="menu2" name="tabset1" type="radio" /><label for="menu2" href='#'>Menu 2</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Eintrag 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think this will introduce many others problems, like 1) Click on Menu 1  does open it, but its not closing 2) No Hover effect 3) I need to hide the input elements 4) I cannot directly tab through my menu, its only possible by a mix of space and tab. But still interesting, thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `tabindex="XXXX"` in your `<a>`tags, when `XXXX` is an incremental number, the tabindex will define the order in what your elements will be focused by the tab key.

So:

```
<ul id='nav'>
  <li><a href='#' tabindex="1">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#' tabindex="2">Eintrag 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' tabindex="3">Eintrag 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#' tabindex="4">Menu 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#' tabindex="5">Eintrag 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' tabindex="6">Eintrag 2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' tabindex="7">Eintrag 3</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' tabindex="8">Eintrag 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

if you need an element to be non-focused, set `tabindex="-1"` to that element.

You need also to modify your CSS, setting the hover state the same as the focus state, to open in focus:

```
 ul#nav > li:hover > ul
 ul#nav > li:focus > ul {
    display: block;
 }
```

Comment: This does not work because you cannot focus a li element. Also I don't think its necessary to label them by tabindex since by default I want to tab through them by DOM order. If I remove **display: none** from the **ul** then the tabbing works fine